# How to model directory synchronization in UML or otherwise

Tags: uml, data-synchronization

How to model - in a UML diagram or similar semi-formal way - an iTunes-like application that synchronizes directory contents. I want to show which data set is the master, and which are the copies that depend on it, which part of the data is always fully synchronized and what may be not fully-synchronized at any given time etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _"3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.."_

Answer (score 0):

use at least two types of diagram. Define classes which interacts within synchronization process .. Directory etc. And use sequence diagram to model interaction (how instances exchange messages and data). Data which are synchronized add to messages as arguments. You can define timing of synchronization using time constraints or by defining initializing time of synchronization process.